# Mounting Windows 8 phone to transfer music

Tags: windows, music, phone

I am trying to mount my Lumia 635 so that I can use Rhythmbox (or any other app) to transfer music. My problem is the windows phone looks like it is recognized as a camera only. So instead of having a mass storage device it mounts it using Shotwell and I can't transfer my music.

Comment: Even if it's mounting it as PTP or something you still ought to be able to open the path in a file browser (even if you have Ubuntu configured to automatically open Shotwell), eh?  Or does the mounted path only show the DCIM directory?

Comment: It didn't work. Idk why, it opened like it should and i put the files in there but for some reason the files didn't appear on my phone

Answer (score 0):

With an android phone, you need to connect to your computer as MTP. The phone should show up in nautilus automatically if you first, install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends mtpfs jmtpfs libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9
```

Reboot for the changes to take effect.

Then, after you plug the phone into the computer, it should automatically connect and appear in Nautilus.

If not, you should have some kind of an option (or maybe the option is in your settings) to connect as either: **a camera** (PTP to transfer photos), as **a media device** (MTP for use with transferring files between android and windows and android to Ubuntu), or as **USB storage** (recommended for XP users although I haven't had any luck with Ubuntu).

Again, you should **select MTP** if at all possible.

Like I said MTP is what you use for an Android when transferring files between android and windows so one can only assume that the people at microsoft would use the same protocol for windows phones as well, however, they have done crazier things in the past :)

Good Luck.